# Node JS db-migrate for different database

Tags: node.js, database, dbmigrate

I'm already using [db-migrate](https://db-migrate.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#db-migrate) package to migrate MySQL database script and it works well, I've even setup the **DATABASE_URL** variable in the server environment.

Now I've a requirement to store few details in the sqlite in the same service, I checked db-migrate package for this feature apparently nothing mentioned regard to the executing sql scripts in multiple different databases at one go. Is it possible to do in db-migrate? or do I've to write my own service for this?

Comment: Try knexJS instead

Comment: did you ever find the solution?

Comment: nope. I've not found a solution to this problem.